# How can I display two decimal digits for a Float number in a string?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am studying basic data types, variables and constants, and made a simulation for an app that displays the price of a coffee beverage, using SwiftUI.

I found a way to arrive at the result I want (to display two decimal houses for the price 16.99), but I don't understand why it works. What is the correct way to display two decimal houses intentionally?

```
var favoriteCoffeePrice: Float = 16.99
```

When I use that variable in a string to display text, like this:

```
Text("R$\(favoriteCoffeePrice)")
```

the app displays 6 decimal houses (R$16.990000). However, if I use String in the interpolation as shown above, it displays two decimal houses (R$16.99), which is what I want.

```
Text("R$\(String(favoriteCoffeePrice))")
```

As a student, I want to know: why does the String definition force the two decimal houses?
And how could I have control over the amount of decimal houses I want to display?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SwiftUI you can use a format specifier in your Text View to define the number decimal places you want. Your example would look like this;

```
Text("\(favoriteCoffeePrice, specifier: "%.2f")")
```

Here is a [link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/localizedstringkey/stringinterpolation/appendinterpolation(_:specifier:)) to the documentation for appendInterpolation(_:specifier:).

Answer (score 1):

To format a number for display as a currency, use `Text`s

```
init(_ input:format:)
```

initialiser with `.currency` as the `format` e.g:

```
Text(favoriteCoffeePrice, format: .currency(code: "BRL"))
```

You can add a `.presentation` modifier to change how it's displayed:

```
struct ContentView: View {
        
    let favoriteCoffeePrice: Float = 16.99
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(favoriteCoffeePrice, format: .currency(code: "BRL"))
            Text(favoriteCoffeePrice, format: .currency(code: "BRL").presentation(.narrow))
            Text(favoriteCoffeePrice, format: .currency(code: "BRL").presentation(.fullName))
            Text(favoriteCoffeePrice, format: .currency(code: "BRL").presentation(.isoCode))
            Text(favoriteCoffeePrice, format: .currency(code: "BRL").presentation(.standard))
        }
    }
}
```

[image]